# How to include multiple OS X images in .travis.yml

Tags: ios, xcode, travis-ci

I am new to travis and I want to include multiple OS X images so i can test my build on different os x platforms like OS X 10.10 and OS X 10.9

> Xcode 7.3 (OS X 10.11) – osx_image: xcode7.3
>
> Xcode 6.4 (OS X 10.10) – osx_image: xcode6.4
>
> Xcode 6.2 (OS X 10.9) – osx_image: beta-xcode6.2

Here is my current .travis.yml

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.3

install:
  - carthage update Nimble Quick --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
  - carthage update Alamofire --no-use-binaries

script:
  - xcodebuild clean test -project Restofire.xcodeproj
    -scheme Restofire-iOS
    -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
    -destination 'name=iPhone 6,OS=9.3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the build matrix to test on different versions of OS X by specifying different `osx_image`, as vaguely explained in [Testing Your Project on Multiple Operating Systems](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/).

Sample .travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c

matrix:
  include:
    - osx_image: xcode7.3
    - osx_image: xcode7.1
```